# Set map service in idle mode in ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, map-service

I am using ESRI suit 10.1 (ArcGIS Desktop, ArcGIS Server, ArcGIS JSAPI 3.3/3.4) at my end and having few performance questions regarding ArcGIS Map service.

-We have three simple map services published on our server.

-Each map services contains query layer and with the help of query layer, we have created few xy events source layer in each map service.

-Integrated those map services in ArcGIS Java script application.

-While querying on the map we are facing load at our sql server database (I think the request coming from client side as we used query layer)

-Interesting thing is that in down time we got request only from arcgis server machine (On 
DB server machine, checked the machine details and host name it’s our arcgis server machine)

So is it possible to set map service in idle mode when not in used? I checked the pooled and non-pooled option but in [10.1, all map services are pooled.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000343000000)

[Going through System Design Strategies](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Server_Software_Performance#Server_process)

Any help regarding this will be great !!

**EDIT**

According to @Alex Tereshenkov answer I can set the minimum number of instance to be zero so

-Is it take time to UP the instance?

-How many no. of instances to be set in Maximum number of instances (default is two)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunil, when you mean idle, do you mean that there are no instances running for the map service when it is not in use by a client? If so, this can be achieved by setting the minimum number of instances to 0 in the Service Properties.

This will not create any ArcSOC.exe process unless there is client submitted requested. Then the instance is created (the maximum number of instances is up to you). Afterwards, when the request was served, the instance shall be destroyed. The time the instance can be running on the server waiting for other requests is defined by another parameter "maximum time an idle instance can be kept running". If you set a really low value, the instance not in use anymore will be destroyed quickly releasing system resources.

Comment: thanks for the reply yes you are correct exactly what you are saying that I want to do. I can set the 0 in the map service. While currently the maximum no of instances option is 2 and we are getting 3 request on our DB server in down time. I am wondering that no one else is using the instance then how on DB server its showing 3?

Comment: That is a bit hard to say for me without investigating the details of your connection to the server. Perhaps the AGS connections stay there in DB connection list for a while even after the instances were destroyed?

Comment: thanks for the reply. After destroying AGS connections there are no AGS connections. Now going to change minimum number of instances to 0 and then review the performance. thanks for quick reply. I will update you soon regarding this..thanks dear : )